# ReactJS Convert my strange array to an object to add it to a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the following array:

```
[{…}]
0: {id: 2, createdAt: "2021-06-11T10:13:46.814Z", exchangedAt: "2021-06-11T08:04:11.415Z", imageUrl: "url", user: "user", …}
1: ....
2: ....
3: ....
....
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I want to convert it to an object and I found this code, but all I receive is the 0:

```
Object.keys(fetchedData.data).map(key => console.log(key))
```

How to access and convert my 5 array values?

Comment: Please provide the input array and your expected result. Your code example just console.log the result of the key you get from the data.

Comment: try this: Object.keys(fetchedData.data).map(key => fetchedData.data[key])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've iterated across your array and used the 'id' field as a key. The key for each object needs to be unique, so this assumes your ID is unique...

```js
const fetchedData = [
      {id: 1, createdAt: "2021-06-11T10:13:46.814Z", exchangedAt: "2021-06-11T08:04:11.415Z", imageUrl: "url", user: "user"},
      {id: 2, createdAt: "2021-06-11T10:13:46.814Z", exchangedAt: "2021-06-11T08:04:11.415Z", imageUrl: "url", user: "user"},
      {id: 3, createdAt: "2021-06-11T10:13:46.814Z", exchangedAt: "2021-06-11T08:04:11.415Z", imageUrl: "url", user: "user"}
    ]
    
obj = {}
    
fetchedData.forEach(x => {
  tempX = {...x}
  delete tempX["id"]
  obj[x.id] = tempX
})
    
console.log('Converted object', obj)

//Using your method, just to log the values without converting it into an object, you could do...
fetchedData.forEach(el => console.log("Individual Element", el))
```

...so when you use `Object.keys()` you are iterating across the keys of an object, but as this is an array of objects, the keys are just the indexes of the array. `.forEach` iterates across the array and gives you each element to work with.

You've used `.map()` in your code, which also iterates through an array, but returns a new array, so you could change each element. `.forEach` just iterates and doesn't return, so you're better off using this for logging to the console.

Comment: You can use SO code snippet. [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/14032355)

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [
  {
     "id":1,
     "createdAt":"2021-06-11T10:13:46.814Z",
     "exchangedAt":"2021-06-11T08:04:11.415Z",
     "imageUrl":"url",
     "user":"user"
  },
  {
     "id":2,
     "createdAt":"2021-06-11T10:13:46.814Z",
     "exchangedAt":"2021-06-11T08:04:11.415Z",
     "imageUrl":"url",
     "user":"user"
  },
  {
     "id":3,
     "createdAt":"2021-06-11T10:13:46.814Z",
     "exchangedAt":"2021-06-11T08:04:11.415Z",
     "imageUrl":"url",
     "user":"user"
  },
  {
     "id":2,
     "createdAt":"2021-06-11T10:13:46.814Z",
     "exchangedAt":"2021-06-11T08:04:11.415Z",
     "imageUrl":"url",
     "user":"user"
  },
  {
     "id":4,
     "createdAt":"2021-06-11T10:13:46.814Z",
     "exchangedAt":"2021-06-11T08:04:11.415Z",
     "imageUrl":"url",
     "user":"user"
  }
]
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
Object.keys(a).map(key => console.log(key))
VM532:1 0
VM532:1 1
VM532:1 2
VM532:1 3
VM532:1 4
```

It is accessing to 5 values.

Comment: You can use SO code snippet. [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/14032355)